# Finding devices in LAN using a server

Tags: macos, networking, ip, xmpp, whatsapp

I am trying to develop a lan chat application. As I looked for the topic, I found that whatsapp, viber etc. use a server which controls all the traffic. The server tells the status of devices and manage all traffic etc. So, what am I trying to know is :

> How the server gets the info of devices like, IP address, MAC address etc?
>
> How the data is transferred from one client to server and then server to another client?
>
> Which language should I use server side?

As shown in image, I want to connect two devices, A and B and interchange data between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure data always through the server. From what I know, the client logs in at the server the first time it connects only. If client A wants to send a message to client B, it retrieves the IP corresponding to username_B from the server, then exchange of data is done directly between client. 
What you should do is to develop a protocol to login at the server and register the client IP, and to retrieve an IP from a username. 
For the routers between server and clients, I think it is out the server scope, you just need for NAT.